Baby Rudin's Theorem 2.12
I ran into the following theorem and proof in baby rubin :

Theorem 2.12. Let $\left\{E_n\right\}$, $n=1,2,\dots$, be a sequence of countable sets, and put
$$
S=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n.
$$
Then $S$ is countable.


Proof. Let every set $E_n$ be arranged in a sequence $\left\{X_{nk}\right\}$, $k=1,2,3,\dots$, and consider the infinite array

                                                            

in which the elements of $E_n$ form the $n$th row. The array contains all elements of $S$. As indicated by the arrows, these elements can be arranged in a sequence

$$
x_{11};x_{21},x_{12};x_{31},x_{22},x_{13};x_{41},x_{32},x_{23},x_{14};\dots\tag{*}
$$

If any two of the sets $E_n$ have elements in common, these will appear more than once in $(*)$. Hence there is a subset $T$ of the set of all positive integers such that $S\sim T$, which shows that $S$ is at most countable. Since $E_1\subset S$, and $E_1$ is infinite, $S$ is infinite, and thus countable. $\blacksquare$

Now I understand that in a way the fact that you're able to arrange all the elements in such sequence makes it countable in the natural sense of the word and have found this answer before in another thread:

Look at the sequence *
$x_{11};x_{21},x_{12};x_{31},x_{22},x_{13};x_{41},x_{32},x_{23},x_{14};…$
Within each ;; add the suffixes.
1+1 =2
2+1 = 1+2 = 3
1+3 = 2+2 = 3+1 = 4
and so on.
So for any positive integer you shall get a countable (finite) number
of such combination and in each case you shall get elements of $S$. If
you remove duplicate items then you shall get a set $S$. This set will
be bijective with the set of natural numbers as for each natural
number you shall get only a finite number of elements.
I hope it is clear now. The bold sequence is constructed by taking
arrows in the matrix. In the matrix the elements of the set $E_i$ are
written in arrow.

but my question is, how can you assert that there's a 1-1 correspondence between $S$ and $T$, which by definition what makes a set countable, when you cannot assign one particular element for every $n \in T$? or is it solely the step of removing duplicates that ensures this correspondence? also if there's a more formal proof that a novice in analysis could still intuit it would be great.

The wording of your question makes your question unclear to me. In other words, I am confused as to what you are saying/asking.

I am confused on what the cardinality of the set $S$ would be. I get that with the Cantor diagonal argument you end up with an index for each diagonal. but how can you claim it's countable when for every index you get multiple (finite though, according to the answer I quoted) elements in $S$.

We can do this without explicitly writing the bijection.
A countable set is one that is in one-to-one correspondence with the natural numbers. If we can show that a set $B$ is countable, then if $A\subset B$, we know that $A$ is at most countable because the assigned enumeration of $B$ can be restricted to $A$.
In the case of the union of countable sets, since each of the $E_i$ are countable, the disjoint union $$\bigsqcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$$ is countable by a direct application of the Cantor diagonal argument. This is the sequence mentioned by Rudin, i.e. $$x_1:x_{21},x_{12}\dots$$ The union is disjoint so no elements need to be removed or skipped. The enumeration is a one-to-one correspondence.
Since the union cannot have more elements than the disjoint union, we know that $$\left\lvert\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n\right\rvert\le\left\lvert\bigsqcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n\right\rvert=\omega$$ where $\omega$ is the cardinality of the natural numbers.
We also know that $$\omega=\lvert E_1\rvert\text{ and } E_1\subset\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n$$ so $$\omega\le\left\lvert\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n\right\rvert$$
Therefore $$\left\lvert\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n\right\rvert=\omega$$

I got it, thank you for your answer!
